# Index created on each column when creating a compound key?

Tags: sql, database, search, indexing

Suppose that I created a compound primary key on col1, col2, col3, will indices be created on each of the column?

I know that the primary key constraint will create index for the combination of (col1, col2, col3) so that the search on these 3 columns will be faster. But I'm not sure if the database will create index on each of the column so that the search on individual column, like search on column2, will be speed up.

Can anybody tell me what happens on these columns in term of index?

Comment: I'm not aware of indexing of specific columns. I think you'll need to add that yourself

Comment: Highly depends on the **actual database** your using (SQL is just the query language.... not a database product). But typically, I would expect that **one index** is created, on the combination of the three columns - but not individual indexes on each column. Such a compound index therefore will only be useful to queries that use the n left-most columns in the index - those using all three, of course, those use `col1, col2`, and those using just `col1` - but this index will **NOT** be useful for queries using only `col3`

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Generally one index will be created so only queries using the "left most" columns can make use of it, i.e. in your example "SELECT * from T where COL2='x'" will not use the index.  That said, Oracle can use an index "skip" where the first column is kind of compressed and the plan can jump past it looking at the next column in.

Your best approach would be to look at the manual and try it in the DBMS of your choice then look at the query plan.

Summary: it depends.